# addToBackStack() duplicating original fragment when pressing back button

Tags: android, transactions, android-listfragment

Whenever I press the back button of my app the following happens.

Original 
Phone display: FragA

After clicking a view on FragA
Phone display: FragB

After clicking back button 
Phone display: 
FragA
FragA

I don't know why FragA is recreated but added to the end of a previous FragA when the back button is pressed. Below is my code.

```
public class ColorListFragment extends ListFragment {
private List<ColorGD> mDrawableList = null;
private ColorAdapter mAdapter = null;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_color_list, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState){

    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        populateList();
        getListView().setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            ColorGD viewItem = mDrawableList.get(position);
            float[] hues = {viewItem.getColor(0),viewItem.getColor(1)};

            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            final String hueValues = "hues";
            args.putFloatArray(hueValues,hues);

            SaturationListFragment sLF = new SaturationListFragment();
            sLF.setArguments(args);

            FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
            transaction.replace(R.id.container,sLF);
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);
            transaction.commit();
        }
    });
}
```

My Main Activity has the following

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    addListFragment();
 }

  public void addListFragment(){
    ColorListFragment cLF = new ColorListFragment();
    FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
    transaction.add(R.id.container,cLF);
    transaction.commit();
  }
}
```

Comment: The display is 2 FragA one FragA directly followed by another FragA.

Comment: Could you edit your original post with these updates?

Comment: The requested edit was made!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think I see what's going on here.  It's actually impossible for the `Fragment` to be duplicated with only one view container.

I suspect that the items in your `ListFragment` are getting duplicated due to the call to `populateList()` in `onActivityCreated()`.

Because`onActivityCreated()` is called every time you click the back button to return to `ColorListFragment` from `SaturationListFragment`, it is calling `populateList()` every time. See [documentation here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onActivityCreated(android.os.Bundle))

In order to fix your issue, just move the call to `populateList()` to `onCreate()`, which is only called the first time the `ListFragment` is initialized:

```
public class ColorListFragment extends ListFragment {
  private List<ColorGD> mDrawableList = null;
  private ColorAdapter mAdapter = null;

  //add the onCreate() override
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstance){
      super.onCreate(savedInstance);
      populateList();  //add this here
  }

  @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_color_list, container, false);
  }

  @Override
  public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState){
      super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
      //populateList();  //remove this
      //..................
```

Comment: Thanks yeah that was the problem!